# JavaScript function with parameters declaration

Tags: javascript, react-native

Having this confusion with react-native (javascript) function declaration

```
_onclick = (resp) => { //some functions }
```

and,

```
_onclick(resp){ //some functions }
```

what is the difference between both declarations? or they are actually the same?

Comment: @Rajesh Not the same really.

Comment: Hi, @Li357can you further explain the difference? What i does understand is if i declared _onclick(resp), the function will need at least 1 parameter to represent resp but on the other hand _onclick = (resp) => is a bit confused to me about the logic

Comment: @Li357 I beg to differ but I have retracted my vote

Comment: @Rajesh This asks about the difference of class property arrow functions vs methods. Your dupe only deals with function expressions not arrow functions specifically. I know there's a better dupe

Comment: @Li357 The answer you picked isn't really a dupe either